# How to import a type definition separately from module import?

Tags: typescript, echarts

I'm trying to understand the connection between type-definitions (from Definitely Typed) and the actual module import.

Let's take the [ECharts](https://github.com/apache/incubator-echarts) library as an example. It comes in different "flavors" available from its `dist` folder. After `npm install echarts` it contains for instance:

```
node_modules/echarts/dist/echarts.js
node_modules/echarts/dist/echarts.min.js
node_modules/echarts/dist/echarts-en.js
node_modules/echarts/dist/echarts-en.min.js
...
```

Installing `@types/echarts` in addition allows to importing it via

```
import * as echarts from "echarts";
```

This works fine both in terms of the resulting JS as well as the type definitions. However the library language is Chinese. The general solution is to import the `echarts-en` flavor of the library, which is identical just using a different language definition file. This can be accomplished by switching to:

```
import * as echarts from "echarts/dist/echarts-en";
```

The resulting JS works fine, and the language is English now. However the TypeScript compiler now complains that it doesn't know type definitions for this import:

```
Could not find a declaration file for module 'echarts/dist/echarts-en'. '/home/<user>/<path>/node_modules/echarts/dist/echarts-en.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm install @types/echarts` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'echarts/dist/echarts-en';
```

Having `@types/echarts` installed doesn't seem enough. How can I tell TypeScript to import the module from `"echarts/dist/echarts-en"`, but use the type definitions matching the `"echarts"` import?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the TypeScript file you should keep original import definitions for `echarts` module:

```js
import * as echarts from "echarts";
```

Path remapping from `echarts` to `node_modules/echarts/dist/echarts-en.js` is task for a bundling software.

For example, with Webpack you would add alias in `webpack.config.js` in [resolve](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/) section:

```
module.exports = {
  //...
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      echarts$: path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/echarts/dist/echarts-en')
    }
  }
};
```

This would remap `import * as echarts from "echarts"` to `echarts-en.js` in your bundle file, while TypeScript intellisense would not be affected.